# Using a reference column to choose between row values in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a large dataframe of around (1200, 10) of mostly string where I have to append a new column say 'Z' based an existing reference column say 'Y', whose values are 'A', 'B', or 'C', from this I need to select one of three corresponding columns in the df say 'D', 'E', or 'F' and append this value as column 'Z'. So the existing table would look something like:

```
   ... T  G  D  E  F  K  ... Y
0   .  .  .  4  6  8  .  ... A
1   .  .  .  1  2  3  .  ... B
2   .  .  .  5  7  9  .  ... B
```

and require:

```
   ... T  G  D  E  F  K  ... Y  Z
0   .  .  .  4  6  8  .  ... A  4
1   .  .  .  1  2  3  .  ... B  2
2   .  .  .  5  7  9  .  ... B  7
```

I'm fairly new to using pandas, so sorry if this seems like an easy problem!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC you need [`DataFrame.lookup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html) and [`Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with a dict to do your custom mappings. Something like:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'T': {0: '.', 1: '.', 2: '.'}, 'G': {0: '.', 1: '.', 2: '.'}, 'D': {0: 4, 1: 1, 2: 5}, 'E': {0: 6, 1: 2, 2: 7}, 'F': {0: 8, 1: 3, 2: 9}, 'K': {0: '.', 1: '.', 2: '.'}, 'Y': {0: 'A', 1: 'B', 2: 'B'}, 'Z': {0: 4, 1: 2, 2: 7}})

d = {'A': 'D', 'B': 'E', 'C': 'F'}

df['Z'] = df.lookup(df.index, df.Y.map(d))

   T  G  D  E  F  K  Y  Z
0  .  .  4  6  8  .  A  4
1  .  .  1  2  3  .  B  2
2  .  .  5  7  9  .  B  7
```

Comment: That is exactly what I was hoping for! Thank you!